# monitor / hook javascript API

Tags: javascript, api, hook, obfuscation, monitor

Imagine having very obfuscated js code. I would like to be able to perform quick analysis, for example to check whether it uses HTML5 Geolocation API (or other API). What's the best method to monitor API calls?

Answer (score 2):

If there event is not in the browser's breakpoints list you can bind debugger manually on function calls there. For geolocation like this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function() { debugger }
```

Or simply

```
var originalGeolocation = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition;

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function() {
  console.log('getCurrentPosition() was called');
  originalGeolocation.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Note that the last line will call the original function maintaining `this` and also passing all the arguments passed to your forked function.